# Aurelia Validation Plugin

Tags: jspm, aurelia

Any idea what is going on with aurelia-validation (the latest version)?  I think something has changed/broken with the versions of the framework/validation I am using.  Here are my dependencies currently:

```
  "aurelia-bootstrapper": "github:aurelia/bootstrapper@^0.18.0",

  "aurelia-framework": "github:aurelia/framework@^0.17.0",

  "aurelia-http-client": "github:aurelia/http-client@^0.12.0",

  "aurelia-validation": "github:aurelia/validation@^0.4.1"
```

As soon as I load the aurelia-validation plugin I get three errors in the chrome console:

Unhandled promise rejection Error: Error invoking TaskQueue. Check the inner error for details.  Is there anywhere I can go to find out what versions of the aurelia framework are currently supported by the validation plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to use latest version of `aurelia-validation` with previous version of other Aurelia libraries.

Latest `aurelia-validation` release is [0.4.1](https://github.com/aurelia/validation/releases), latest `aurelia-framework` is [0.18.0](https://github.com/aurelia/framework/releases), `aurelia-bootstrapper` [0.19.0](https://github.com/aurelia/bootstrapper/releases) and `aurelia-http-client` [0.13.0](https://github.com/aurelia/http-client/releases).

Either upgrade all Aurelia libraries to [latest version](http://blog.durandal.io/2015/11/10/aurelia-pre-beta-release/) or try to downgrade `aurelia-validation` to 0.4.0.

Comment: Upgrading everything worked, downgrading to 0.4.0 did not.  Thank you for the advice!